# RAF (Fujifilm RAW) preview on a Mac

Tags: raw, fujifilm, macintosh, macbook, fujifilm-x100

Is there a way to see the preview of the RAW files from my Fuji X10 (extension .RAF) while I use Finder on my MacBook? Photoshop CS6 correctly opens these files but I must open them one by one...

Comment: When you say preview, do you mean open in Preview (the program)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but no, not directly - but you can try free beta of FastRawViewer, http://www.fastrawviewer.com/ and send the selected ones to Photoshop.

Comment: Any chance you're affiliated with the product? It's a good manner to disclose your affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fuji's software page for the X10](http://www.fujifilm.com/support/digital_cameras/software/firmware/x/x10/), their firmware revision 1.03 and above have support for OS X 10.7. There is no mention of support however for other Mac OS versions. Further, there is no mention of support from any of the Mac Raw Technical notes. [10.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3825) [10.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4757) [10.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5371?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) [10.9](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5955). I suggest that you post the version of the OS you are using, and see if people can identify any experience with 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

One free open source alternative to view and edit the RAF files from the X10 in OSX is Darktable, which also works on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OSX supports the X10's RAW. [The X20's RAW is supported in Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4757), [Mountain Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5371) and [Mavericks](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5955), but there's no mention of the X10.

Answer (score 0):

yeah photoshop can do that but did  try it on OSX 10.9?? 
you can have the ACDSEE mac pro 3 for both editing and viewing
http://www.acdsee.com/en/products/acdsee-pro-3-mac

hope it'll help ...